# Can we limit the no. Of index linked to an alias in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5, spring-data-elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch we know that we can assign multiple no. Of index to an alias. So my question here ,is there a way by changing the configuration or something in Elasticsearch by which I can specify that a particular alias  can have this maximum number of index assigned to it.
I am looking at max no of index assigned to a alias be 1 only. Any suggestions and thought is this is most welcome.

Comment: I'm curious to learn more about your use case. Do you mind to explain why you'd want such a restriction?

Comment: @Val actually this will be an workaround , as currently in my project we are having an index with a provided alias being created, but due to some rogue script or code another index is being created and the same alias is being mapped.Due to this any data which is being indexed fails which is the expected because Es will not be able to know which index to route to. After lot of crazy troubleshooting we aren't able to find the root cause of creation of new index. So as a temporary fix will like to use this work around which could give us time to explore the root cause.

Comment: Well, to my knowledge there's no way to prevent that, unless you have security enabled so you could prevent un given user/role from creating a new index. Are you using index templates by any chance? If yes, then you could maybe modify that template to prevent the alias to be assigned to the newly created index.